# Does using constants save memory

Tags: c++, memory, arduino, constants

I am currently refactoring a class I wrote for an university projekt.

The class draws stuff onto a TFT display connected to an Arduino Nano, 
and I think I don't need to explain why memory is rare on microprocessors,
especially on Arduino Nanos....

The class draws a GUI over the screen, and before refactoring I used to set **magic numbers** for everything drawing related, for example the offset from the screen edge.

I was able to refactor this kind of stuff with

```
//constants for screen offsets
const int PROGMEM _titleHeight = 30;
const int PROGMEM _leftOffset = 22;
const int PROGMEM _charHeight = 15;
... more stuff here, you get the point
```

Then I was wondering "does this really save any memory" ?
I mean, in the end I use 3 Integer cells more to achieve the same goal, which are 96 bit "wasted" space.

Beside the fact that it's easier to read and I stuff these values into PROGMEM anyway, 
**does using constants in general save any space in terms of optimization?**

EDIT: if these values where shorts, would a pointer to them not be of 32bit and thus waste 16bit? Am I getting stuff wrong?

Comment: As long as you don't odr-use them, a good compiler should be able to optimize them away.

Comment: Given that constants that aren't declared `extern` are "internally linked" in C++, the compiler knows that no other compilation unit will use that object. As long as you don't take their address (that includes passing them by reference), the compiler has no reason to put the constants in memory

Comment: There are circumstances where the compiler would not be able so save memory with constants. One particular example would be that if you take the address of the variable, then it needs to have a memory location. However, in most cases, the compiler can probably avoid storing those values in memory (and do other tricks like constant folding which could also save processing time). **** However, the main advantage of constants is  programmer clarity rather than any compile time savings.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This means, if we assume the Arduino c++ compiler is optimised for microcontrollers, it should not waste the program memory and "drop" these variables at compile time?

Comment: My answer here would be "trust the compiler, but help it". If something is constant, just declare it as a constant, it can't take more memory than if you declare it as a variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way that old-school programmers save resources even in debug builds is by using enums:

```
enum {
    _titleHeight = 30,
    _leftOffset = 22,
    _charHeight = 15
};
```

Now there is certainly no memory used by these values.  However, an optimizing compiler should arrive at the same end result with your `const int` values.

The only way to be sure is to try it, and measure.